# How to programmatically set Authentication Token in Jenkins groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm looking to set the Authentication Token in groovy similar to how I setup other options for the build:

```
properties([[$class: 'BuildConfigProjectProperty'], 
   buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '25')),
   parameters([
     password(name: 'aws_access_key', defaultValue: 'AWS Access Key', description: 'Enter AWS Access Key ID'), 
])])
```

The field I wish to set (from the UI):

[Picture of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPZkh.png)

How does one set this field?